# How to remotely install server via root

Tags: linux, web-server, dedicated-server

I would like to know if it is possible to remotely install a server OS via root. 
If it is possible, how can it be done?

This question might be strange or impossible, so I have listed my assumptions below.

**Assumptions**

- You have purchased a dedicated server with access to root.
- You don't have physical access to the server.
- You don't want the hosting company to install the operating system (They would install the OS using a non-English language).
- The server OS will be a linux distro such as Ubuntu or CentOS.

If you have an alternate solution (Example- Have the hosting company install the OS then change the language), I'd love to hear it.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't really reinstall (it is possible but its something admins do to see how complex they can make something to fill up Saturday evenings) via just root access. You usually need some sort of virtual console like a KVM or IPMI to do the install.  That said it would probably be better to have them do the install and then just make sure LOCALE is set properly to the language you want to use:

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Locale

Comment: You can also set the LOCALE later, via ssh.